# mongoDB method returns undefined despite everything being correct

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, crud

**CASE DESCRIPTION:**
I'm building a fullstack chat application on node.js (with Express), socket.io and mongoDB. Everything works fine until a moment when user puts the sign-up data that's already used in another account. I have created two functions: first to check if the username like query one already exists and second one for email addresses. (All the functions connecting with db are using callbacks to ensure proper ansynchronous working, also I have tried creating local variable and assigning a value (t/f) to it and returning it, still being 'undefined').

```
usernameExists = function(username){
    var query = {
        username: username
    }
    mongodb.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, db){
        var chat = db.db('chat');
        chat.collection('users').countDocuments(query, function(err, number){
            if (number > 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Email one:

```
emailExists = function(email){
    var query = {
        email: email
    }
    mongodb.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, db){
        var chat = db.db('chat');
        chat.collection('users').countDocuments(query, function(err, number){
            if (number > 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**
When the user puts the data into form on the frontend even the exactly same document is created in the database. I have tried logging the number and the result of this methods: number seems to be good (>0), however result is 'undefined'. 
**In advance thanks for any help!**

Comment: Try `usernameExists = function (username, done) {
    var query = {
        username: username
    }
    mongodb.connect(dburl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
        var chat = db.db('chat');
        chat.collection('users').countDocuments(query, function (err, number) {
            if (number > 0) {
                done(null, true);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
}`

Comment: and `emailExists = function (email, done) {
    var query = {
        email: email
    }
    mongodb.connect(dburl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
        var chat = db.db('chat');
        chat.collection('users').countDocuments(query, function (err, number) {
            if (number > 0) {
                done(null, true);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
}`